# Parallel HTTPS connection remote and local host

Tags: tls

Let's assume we've a architecture like this:

[HTTPS JSON API] <-- INTERNET --> [Single-Page-Webapplication using XHR] <---> [Locally installed HTTP Server]

The users browser would refuse the connection to the local HTTP because of Mixed Content policy. So how would we implement the communication in this case?

Comment: Strict Transport Security is for a domain.

Comment: Fixed this, the problem here is mixed content policy.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the same-origin policy,  JavaScript running on a remote site cannot use an XHR to access content running on another domain.  [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://enable-cors.org/) is one solution to this problem.

The server running on localhost, can define a CORS header which permits JavaScript running on a specific domain access to the server.